# Google Api Client re-login specific user

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client, google-api-client

In my web app, I'm integrating a "Sign In With Google" button with [Google Api Client (JS)](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js), in order to then integrate with some other Google services.

So far I've already implemented the login logic: the user is able to click the button and proceed to the application, the flow is this:

- the user accepts to connect the app to its google account
- `then` I send the response token to my backend (PHP) to check the token and store in the DB the Google UserID (`sud`)
- If the user had already an account with my app, I update the profile to add the google sign in option.
- If the user did not have an account I ask him to register client side.
- from now on the user can access my app both with my app's login credentials, and with "Google Sign In".
- I send back to the client the access authorization to my app.

My problem is, how to sign in the user automatically the next time? At least two scenarios my happen:

1. the user opens my app from the computer of a friend in which another google account is already logged in. The user chooses to login in my app with my app's credentials (not "Google Sign In"), so once he/she is logged in, by refreshing the token I would get the wrong Google account. Displaying the authorization window again wouldn't be ideal and would surely offset the user seeing someone else's account.
2. the user opens my app in `incognito (private) mode` on a friends' computer, and he/she chooses to login using his/her email and password, not the google sign in. Again, I wouldn't know how to re-sign in the user with the google api client.

Since I know in my backend what Google user is "my user", is there a way to pass such information to the google client api, so that it logs in the right user?